# How to get ImageView Size in Android?

Tags: java, android

Im trying to get imageview size but its returning zero. i know its because im calling it in onCreate(). can anyone help me how to do this so that when I will click a button it will show me the size of that ImageView. here what i have tried so far...

```
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
            imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgView);        

            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    getSize();              
                }
            });

        }

void getSize)
    {
        BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable)imgView.getDrawable();
        bmp = bd.getBitmap();           
        Bitmap op = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, imgWidth/2, imgHeight/2, imgWidth, imgHeight);

        imgView.setImageBitmap(op);     
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus){
        imgWidth=imgView.getWidth();
        imgHeight=imgView.getHeight();
    }
```

**UPDATE**

This is what I am getting right now...

```
06-18 00:13:20.206: E/AndroidRuntime(919): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-18 00:13:20.206: E/AndroidRuntime(919): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: x must be >= 0
06-18 00:13:20.206: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.checkXYSign(Bitmap.java:225)
06-18 00:13:20.206: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:495)
06-18 00:13:20.206: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:471)
06-18 00:13:20.206: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at com.example.bitmapfun.Main.Gray(Main.java:44)
06-18 00:13:20.206: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at com.example.bitmapfun.Main$1.onClick(Main.java:34)
06-18 00:13:20.206: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3527)
06-18 00:13:20.206: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14234)
06-18 00:13:20.206: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
06-18 00:13:20.206: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-18 00:13:20.206: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-18 00:13:20.206: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
06-18 00:13:20.206: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-18 00:13:20.206: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-18 00:13:20.206: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-18 00:13:20.206: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-18 00:13:20.206: E/AndroidRuntime(919):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Maybe try to use `imgView.getLayoutParamas().width` and `imgView.getLayoutParamas().height` instead of `getWidth()` and `getHeight()`.

Comment: viewTreeobsrver() is the way to go

Comment: @G.T. getLayoutParams() not working for me .. giving same error..

Comment: @IllegalArgument could you please tell me or show me the code how to use viewTreeobsrver() inside the button onclick method thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the `onWindowFocusChange()` method is called? Can you check it with the debugger?

Comment: @G.T. i have attached my logcat info .. thanks

Comment: you need to do something like if(hasfocus) do your work

Answer (score 1):

Try this it uses view tree observer for getting the width and height. The earlier methods didnot work because the view was not drawn in the screen(layout pass incomplete). Something similar should work:

```
final ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
ViewTreeObserver vto = iv.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
       Log.d("width",""+iv.getWidth());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The size isn't set up until the component is added to the parent window, and then the window is "packed" or **laid out** to the right size. So in the `onCreate`, it will be `0,0`

Can't you just get the size when the function is called?

```
void getSize()
    {
      imgWidth=imgView.getWidth();
      imgHeight=imgView.getHeight();
      BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable)imgView.getDrawable();
      bmp = bd.getBitmap();           
      Bitmap op = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, imgWidth/2, imgHeight/2, imgWidth, imgHeight);

      imgView.setImageBitmap(op);     
    }
```

Comment: why are setting bitmap in function like getSize()?

Comment: That is a good question! I just called it `getSize` cos that's what the OP called it. Although in his stack trace it appears to be called `Gray`...